# query parameter in schema level expdp

Tags: oracle, schema, expdp

Using query parameter in oracle **expdp** we export subset of table that's fine but can we export subset of particular schema data without mentioning particular table . 
example. i want to export HR schema and i want expdp to export all data of HR schema for the last few days only without mentioning tables in it.

Comment: How will you identify which data you want - what does 'data for the last few days' mean? Do you have a timestamp column on every table that you can apply a query filter to? Even if you did, what would happen with referential integrity - if you export a new child record but not its old parent, that wouldn't be very useful. And what will you do with the exported data, repeatedly import elsewhere? Sounds like you're trying to reinvent incremental backups.

Comment: agree with you . i had a scenario where i have to export few schema with last 30 days data in it . Implementing  query parameter for all table in that schema is tedious that's why i'm looking if there is something we can do it via query parameter in schema level expdp . it seems like it's out of league.